# How to append elements to a nested layer

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to append a rect inside a nested layer for an svg stacked chart I'm putting together.

To start with I have the following:

```
layers = svg.selectAll('g.layer')
    .data(stacked, function(d) {
        return d.dataPointLegend;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', function(d) {
        return d.dataPointLegend;
    });

layers.selectAll('g.layer')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.dataPointValues;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('g');
```

Which renders `<g class="someclass"><g></g></g>` in the DOM

What I would then like to do, is for each data point in the `dataPointValues` collection and a `rect` and `text` element.

I have tried

layers.selectAll('g.layer')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.dataPointValues;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect');

Which I know is wrong since I end up with

```
<g class="someclass"><g></g><rect></rect></g>
```

What I want is

```
<g class="someclass"><g><rect></rect></g></g>
```

So when appending the second level layer, how do I then add the next level `rect` element?

This may seem like over nesting, but I want a layer per data point as each data point may have one or multiple elements representing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to get what you want. The only thing missing is to use another variable for `layers`. Here is the snippet:

First, for creating the outer groups, it's exactly as you did:

```
var layers = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
        .data(/*whatever*/)
        .enter()
        .append("g");
```

Then, instead of using `layers` again, we create another variable:

```
var innerLayers = layers.selectAll("g.layer")
        .data(/*whatever*/)
        .enter()
        .append("g");
```

This creates the groups within the groups. And, finally, we use `innerLayers` to append the rects:

```
innerLayers.selectAll(".rects")
        .data(/*whatever*/)
        .enter()
        .append("rect");
```

Doing this way, you have what you want:

```
<g class="someclass"><g><rect></rect></g></g>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the same solution just as you posted it, but it's good to know I was thinking along the right lines! :)